# Pandas : Obtaining column name for sorted value at record level

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe as below :

[image]

Now i need to obtain the top 2 max value column names for each record.I can do sorting using np.sort but how do i obtain the column names for each record ? E.g for record 0 , i need to obtain column names ['beta','gamma'] as max value is from gamma (4.1) and second max is from beta(2.1).And so on for all records

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is important use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values and get columns names by indexing:

```
arr = df.columns.values[np.argsort(-(df).values)[:, :2]]
print (arr)
[['gama' 'beta']
 ['beta' 'gama']
 ['gama' 'beta']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index).rename(columns=lambda x: f'top_{x+1}')
print (df1)
  top_1 top_2
0  gama  beta
1  beta  gama
2  gama  beta
```

If performance is not important:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.nlargest(2).index for _, x in df.T.items()])
print (df1)
      0     1
0  gama  beta
1  beta  gama
2  gama  beta
```

Comment: Just to note - it almost looks like the OP (unless they're doing something really specific here) might just be better off with a data-structure produced by something like: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(2).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` - but not sure - so just throwing it out there...

Comment: @JonClements - There is necessary cumcount, so rather added solution with list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

use [`Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

```
new_df = ( df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2),axis=1).notna()
             .dot(df.add_prefix('_').columns)
             .str.split('_',expand=True)
             .iloc[:,1:]

          )
print(new_df)
       1      2
0   beta  gamma
1   beta  gamma
2  alpha  gamma
```